# Springboot finds files in src/main/webapp but not src/main/webapp/anything

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Sprint boot to run a web application. I did not configure any classes explicitly. I have a strange problem. When running the web server using gradle bootRun, I am able to access files that are directly under webapp folder but not a sub-folder like webapp/something.

I'm not posting any code here because there is nothing explicitly I configured different from a default spring boot web app. I'm using structure as in https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gradle

Anyone faced this problem before ?

Comment: What do you mean `webapp/something`? Have you ever checked your out or target directory for `somthing` existence?

Comment: I hate myself for searching file in a wrong directory and wasting several hours.